# Why can't Python 3 virtualenv find some installed packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, odoo, odoo-13

I am working with a Python virtualenv named `env` to execute Odoo. In the virtualenv `bin` directory, I got this:

```
pip
pip3
pip3.8

python -> /usr/bin/python3
python3 -> python
python3.8 -> python
```

And the Odoo service is running this command to execute Odoo (as you can see, using the `python3.8` of the virtualenv):

```
ExecStart=/opt/odoo/env/bin/python3.8 /opt/odoo/odoo_13/src/oca/OCB/odoo-bin -c /opt/odoo/odoo_13/config/.odoo.conf
```

The problem is that every now and again, Odoo gives the following critical error and the instance stops working:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug'

It seems that the `werkzeug` package is not installed, but, if I do the following:

```
anubia@my-server:/opt/odoo$ . env/bin/activate

(env) anubia@my-server:/opt/odoo$ which pip
/opt/odoo/env/bin/pip

(env) anubia@my-server:/opt/odoo$ which pip3
/opt/odoo/env/bin/pip3

(env) anubia@my-server:/opt/odoo$ which pip3.8
/opt/odoo/env/bin/pip3.8

(env) anubia@my-server:/opt/odoo$ pip3.8 install werkzeug
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug in ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.11.15)

(env) anubia@my-server:/opt/odoo$ cd env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
Display all 125 possibilities? (y or n)
Babel-2.9.1.dist-info/             attrs-21.2.0.dist-info/            docutils/                          numpy-1.21.0.dist-info/            python_stdnum-1.16.dist-info/      urllib3-1.26.6.dist-info/
Crypto/                            babel/                             docutils-0.17.1.dist-info/         numpy.libs/                        pytz/                              validate_email-1.3.dist-info/
Jinja2-3.0.1.dist-info/            bcrypt/                            gevent/                            paramiko/                          pytz-2021.1.dist-info/             vatnumber/
MarkupSafe-2.0.1.dist-info/        bcrypt-3.2.0.dist-info/            gevent-21.1.2.dist-info/           paramiko-2.7.2.dist-info/          reportlab/                         vatnumber-1.2.dist-info/
OpenSSL/                           cached_property-1.5.2.dist-info/   greenlet/                          passlib/                           reportlab-3.5.68.dist-info/        werkzeug/
PIL/                               cachetools/                        greenlet-1.1.0.dist-info/          passlib-1.7.4.dist-info/           reportlab.libs/                    wheel/
Pillow-8.3.1.dist-info/            cachetools-4.2.2.dist-info/        html2text/                         phonenumbers/                      requests/                          wheel-0.36.2.dist-info/
Pillow.libs/                       certifi/                           html2text-2020.1.16.dist-info/     phonenumbers-8.12.27.dist-info/    requests-2.25.1.dist-info/         xlrd/
PyNaCl-1.4.0.dist-info/            certifi-2021.5.30.dist-info/       idna/                              pip/                               requests_file-1.5.1.dist-info/     xlrd-2.0.1.dist-info/
PyPDF2/                            cffi/                              idna-2.10.dist-info/               pip-21.3.1.dist-info/              requests_toolbelt/                 xlsxwriter/
PyPDF2-1.26.0.dist-info/           cffi-1.14.5.dist-info/             isodate/                           pkg_resources/                     requests_toolbelt-0.9.1.dist-info/ xlwt/
PyYAML-3.12.dist-info/             cffi.libs/                         isodate-0.6.0.dist-info/           polib-1.1.1.dist-info/             sassutils/                         xlwt-1.3.0.dist-info/
Unidecode-1.2.0.dist-info/         chardet/                           jinja2/                            psutil/                            setuptools/                        xmlsig/
Werkzeug-0.11.15.dist-info/        chardet-4.0.0.dist-info/           libsass-0.21.0.dist-info/          psutil-5.8.0.dist-info/            setuptools-57.1.0.dist-info/       xmlsig-0.1.5.dist-info/
XlsxWriter-1.4.4.dist-info/        cryptography/                      lxml/                              psycopg2/                          six-1.16.0.dist-info/              yaml/
__pycache__/                       cryptography-3.4.7.dist-info/      lxml-4.6.3.dist-info/              psycopg2-2.9.1.dist-info/          stdnum/                            zeep/
_distutils_hack/                   dateutil/                          markupsafe/                        pyOpenSSL-20.0.1.dist-info/        suds/                              zeep-4.0.0.dist-info/
appdirs-1.4.4.dist-info/           decorator-5.0.9.dist-info/         nacl/                              pycparser/                         suds_jurko-0.6.dist-info/          zope/
asn1crypto/                        defusedxml/                        num2words/                         pycparser-2.20.dist-info/          tests/                             zope.event-4.5.0.dist-info/
asn1crypto-1.4.0.dist-info/        defusedxml-0.7.1.dist-info/        num2words-0.5.10.dist-info/        pycryptodome-3.10.1.dist-info/     unidecode/                         zope.interface-5.4.0.dist-info/
attr/                              docopt-0.6.2.dist-info/            numpy/                             python_dateutil-2.8.1.dist-info/   urllib3/
```

So `werkzeug` seems to be installed. What is the problem?

**EDIT**

After trying with @ChesuCR answer two weeks, the Odoo server stopped working again. This time the error is:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'`

However, if I check the `virtualenv`:

```
myuser@myserver:/opt/odoo$ . venv3.7/bin/activate
(venv3.7) myuser@myserver:/opt/odoo$ which python3.7
/opt/odoo/venv3.7/bin/python3.7
(venv3.7) myuser@myserver:/opt/odoo$ python3.7 -m pip install PyPDF2
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in ./venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.26.0)
(venv3.7) myuser@myserver:/opt/odoo$ python3.7 -m pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
appdirs           1.4.4
attrs             21.2.0
Babel             2.6.0
beautifulsoup4    4.10.0
cached-property   1.5.2
certifi           2021.10.8
cffi              1.15.0
chardet           3.0.4
cryptography      36.0.0
decorator         4.3.0
defusedxml        0.7.1
docutils          0.14
ebaysdk           2.1.5
gevent            1.5.0
greenlet          0.4.15
html2text         2018.1.9
idna              2.8
isodate           0.6.0
Jinja2            2.10.1
libsass           0.17.0
lxml              4.3.2
Mako              1.0.7
MarkupSafe        1.1.0
mock              2.0.0
num2words         0.5.6
ofxparse          0.19
passlib           1.7.1
pbr               5.8.0
Pillow            6.1.0
pip               21.3.1
polib             1.1.0
psutil            5.6.6
psycopg2          2.7.7
pyasn1            0.4.8
pyasn1-modules    0.2.8
pycparser         2.21
pydot             1.4.1
pyOpenSSL         21.0.0
pyparsing         2.2.0
PyPDF2            1.26.0
pyserial          3.4
python-dateutil   2.7.3
python-stdnum     1.17
pytz              2019.1
pyusb             1.0.2
qrcode            6.1
reportlab         3.5.13
requests          2.21.0
requests-toolbelt 0.9.1
setuptools        57.5.0
six               1.16.0
soupsieve         2.3.1
urllib3           1.24.3
vatnumber         1.2
vobject           0.9.6.1
Werkzeug          0.14.1
wheel             0.37.0
xlrd              1.1.0
XlsxWriter        1.1.2
xlwt              1.3.0
zeep              3.2.0
```

And of course Odoo is running with the Python interpreter of the `virtualenv`:

```
ExecStart=/opt/odoo/venv3.7/bin/python3.7 /opt/odoo/odoo_13/src/oca/OCB/odoo-bin -c /opt/odoo/odoo_13/config/.odoo.conf
```

Comment: It's weird for `python` inside a virtualenv to be just a symlink to `/usr/bin/python3`. Try creating a new virtualenv alongside this one.

Comment: Is there maybe another python path defined at the top of `/opt/odoo/odoo_13/src/oca/OCB/odoo-bin`? Something like `#!/usr/bin/python`?
According to https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo-bin this might be the case.
Maybe this is somehow conflicting.

Comment: @tripleee that's true, my old `virtualenvs` have their own Python command interpreter, but the new ones, regardless the server, point to the local command interpreter... I've tried to create another `virtualenv` but same result.

Comment: @rocksteady this is the case. The `odoo-bin` has the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. But does the shebang taken into account when the file is executed with a specific command interpreter, like in this case?

Comment: Indeed, the shebang is ignored if you run `python scriptname`; the trick then of course is to make sure `python` points to the right instance of Python.

Comment: How are you creating these virtual environments? The standard command with Python 3 would be `python3 -m venv envname`

Comment: I use `virtualenv -p python3 env` or just `virtualenv env` to create the virtuaenv. If I use your command I get an error: **The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available. On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv package using the following command: apt install python3.8-venv. You may need to use sudo with that command. After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment. Failing command: ['/opt/odoo/envname/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']**.

Comment: It might also help to check ` /opt/odoo/env/bin/python3.8 -m site` to see the available directories.

Comment: That returns this:
```sys.path = [
    '/opt/odoo',
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
    '/opt/odoo/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/anubia/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/anubia/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False```

Comment: As @tripleee mentioned, I would also try and install `python3.8-venv`, then create the virtualenv using `python3 -m venv envname`.

Comment: I've installed `python3.8-venv` and afterwards I've created a new virtualenv with `python3 -m venv envname`. This new virtualenv has two command interpreters (python and python3) instead of three (python, python3 and python3.8). Besides, they're all symbolic links to the local Python command interpreters, so if that was the problem, it is not fixed. Odoo cannot work without `werkzeug` package, so I can't explain why, with my other virtualenv, Odoo runs OK, and you can work with it, but after a while, it falls down complaining about the `werkzeug` library.

Comment: @tripleee rocksteady After two days, the Odoo service has stopped again with exactly the same error, in spite of installing the virtualenv as you said. May be as ChesuCR answer says, it is not a problem of the virtualenv but the packages versions installed inside. I'll try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Odoo 13 is [not compatible with the Python 3.8 version](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/40232). You can try with Python 3.7 or 3.6 versions. Anyway, many issues have been fixed, so I am not sure about the Python 3.8 incompatibility. But, in principle, the branch Odoo v13 was created for Python 3.6, as you can check in the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/setup.py#L59) file

If the problem still bothers you, try to install the exact versions that Odoo developers posted in the [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/requirements.txt) file, where dependencies should have been tested. So you can install the right Werzeug version:

```
pip install Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Ah, and if you want to show all the installed packages you can do:

```
pip list
```

Comment: I'll try this and give you feedback after some days. Thank you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution seems not to work neither. I've edited my question.

Comment: I see, you have tried with Python3.7 as I can read in your edited question, try with python 3.6 and check if you get the same error or any other different problem

Comment: God leads us in most unexpected ways.

Comment: In fact, if you check the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/setup.py#L59) you can chech that says v3.6. So, in principle, that branch was created for that version.

Comment: I have edited my answer with this data :clap: :clap:

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try to 3.6 version meanwhile. I'll give you the results in two weeks aprox I guess.

Comment: After trying it all this time, I got the same errors with 3.6. All of a sudden the service falls down complaining about a missing Python library which actually is already installed in the virtualenv. Same packages installed on the host do not give these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Odoo is, but in order to find the packages, you usually need to "activate" the virtualenv. Just like you did manually, but you also need that when Odoo is running the program. It is not enough to just call the correct python binary. So you can either try to have Odoo activate the venv before it starts the program, or if not possible, emulate doing that (it's probably mostly setting PATH and PYTHONPATH environment variables)

Comment: But the venv docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) say the following: _You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path, so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual environment’s Python automatically._ So, what should I do then?

Comment: It's the first time I see that doc, and I would intuitively interpret it as you are. But if read more litterally, it speaks about *running* a *script* *installed* in the venv, while you are trying to import modules installed there

Comment: Do you mean that I should put my scripts inside the `virtualenv` folder? Because I think I should never do that. Pasting a whole ERP like Odoo inside a `virtualenv` is not a good idea. The `virtualenv` is not for holding customized projects inside, isn't it?

Comment: No, you should have odoo, before it runs the python stuff, set variables PYTHONPATH etc (by activating the venv)

Comment: I have to find out some info about that to see how it works and try what you say. Thank you.

Comment: After trying a bit it seems that the venv works as advertised (as you thought). But I suspect that's only valid for the initial python process. If the odoo script then spawns additional processes (without doing some particular things to preserve the venv) the paths will get lost. Env variables might help

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to fix it like this:

1. First of all and a key point is that I had to use ***root*** user, not ubuntu not odoo nothing, only ***root***
2. I activated my venv in *root* user
3. I installed required packages: ***pip3 install paramiko*** (or any other packages: ***boto3***, or ***pretty-bad-protocol***)

and then I could install the module from the odoo admin backend, and it's working just fine